# Why does shadowing affect `final` behavior?

Tags: java, final

Here are three SSCCE which I believe should compile and behave the same.  The only thing I'm changing is the first line of "run".

**Exhibit 1**

```
public class FinalExperiment {
    private TinyThing thing;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinalExperiment instance = new FinalExperiment();
        instance.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        final TinyThing thing = new TinyThing();
        System.out.println("Got a thing here: " + thing);
    }

    private static class TinyThing {
        public TinyThing() {}
        public String toString() { return "Hello!"; }
    }
}
```

This works; it compiles successfully, and prints: "Got a thing here: Hello!"

**Exhibit 2**

```
public class FinalExperiment {
    private TinyThing thing;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinalExperiment instance = new FinalExperiment();
        instance.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        final TinyThing otherThing = thing;
        System.out.println("Got a thing here: " + otherThing);
    }

    private static class TinyThing {
        public TinyThing() {}
        public String toString() { return "Hello!"; }
    }
}
```

This works; it compiles successfully, and prints: "Got a thing here: null"

**Exhibit 3**

```
public class FinalExperiment {
    private TinyThing thing;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinalExperiment instance = new FinalExperiment();
        instance.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        final TinyThing thing = thing;
        System.out.println("Got a thing here: " + thing);
    }

    private static class TinyThing {
        public TinyThing() {}
        public String toString() { return "Hello!"; }
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with this message:

```
FinalExperiment.java:10: error: variable thing might not have been initialized
            final TinyThing thing = thing;
                                    ^
1 error
```

Why?  The only difference between Exhibit 2 and 3 is that I'm shadowing `thing` in my `run` method.  It doesn't seem like the compiler should care more simply because shadowing is taking place.

Comment: Because `thing` is in scope inside its initializer.

Comment: Also, `final` is irrelevant.

Comment: Its because thing in your run method is defined as final. And yet it is never initialized. Final references must be initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, shadowing is occurring in Exhibit 3, but in effect you are attempting to declare a `final` variable, then assign it to itself.

```
final TinyThing thing = thing;  // Assign to self!
```

It hasn't been assigned a value yet, so you get the compiler error that it's not initialized.  This occurs whether the local variable `thing` is `final` or not.

To refer to the instance variable, qualify it with `this`.

```
final TinyThing thing = this.thing;  // Bypass shadowing.
```

This compiles and leads to the same output as Exhibit 2:

```
Got a thing here: null
```

This example fails to compile in the same way, for instance:

```
public class SelfDefineExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, this gives the same error: `final TinyThing t = t;`. The shadowing issue is irrelevant - the problem is assigning to self.

Comment: Thanks, that's really suprising to me.  I'm surprised that the compiler considers variables to be in scope in the right side of any initial definition.  I can't ever imagine that's ever right, which is why I thought the shadowing "wouldn't have taken effect yet" in my example.

Comment: @CoryKendall The right-hand side of the assignment is "after" the left-hand side so it can see the declaration. It might not be useful but it's logical.

Answer (score 1):

When doing `final TinyThing thing = thing` you refer to self variable which is not yet initialized.

You can fix this doing `final TinyThing thing = this.thing;`

Which would output

> Got a thing here: null

Note that the `final` keyword won't change anything on the behaviour here.

This have nothing to do with shadowing, you can test it with any other values.

For example : `Object a = a` will give the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are in scope for their own definitions. This:

```
int i = i;
```

tries to initialize a variable with its own value. But it doesn't have a value, because it hasn't been initialized yet! Hence the error.